# ASP.NET Roles and Membership

Tags: asp.net, roles, membership, elevated-privileges

I am quite new to ASP.NET technologies

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Agency,Admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have the above web.config for a folder, there is a requirement to give an elevated priviledge to some users in Agency role to access a page called AddOrganisation.aspx.
To solve this, I think I can add the following markup to the web.config but this will be static

```
<location path="AddOrganization.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="wale, etc, etc"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

How can I enable adding users programmatically instead of updating the web.config for each change?

I will be grateful for your responses. Thank you

Comment: You need to assign new users a Role, and then use the <allow roles="somerole"/> entry instead of <allow users="userone,usertwo,etc"/>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not make changes the web config at runtime, this will restart your application, every time you add a user. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ackhksh7.aspx) says this

> Configuration Changes Cause a Restart of the Application Domain
>
> Changes to configuration settings in Web.config files indirectly cause
>   the application domain to restart. This behavior occurs by design. You
>   can optionally use the configSource attribute to reference external
>   configuration files that do not cause a restart when a change is made.
>   For more information, see configSource in General Attributes Inherited
>   by Section Elements.

Instead you should give those users a different role, so that only those users can access the 
"AddOrganisation.aspx" page.

Or else you can also do another thing if you dont want to create another role for these users. You keep on adding these users to a table and whenever a request is made to the page you can check if the users name is present in the table or not and then allow/deny the user.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. I eventually created a Role-Permissions table. Everything now works fine. Thanks for the enlightening

Comment: @user2294513 - Glad that it helped you. You can mark it as your answer in that case. :)